# .filter not a function error?

Tags: javascript, function, filter

Created a function that returns the sum of the two lowest positive integers from an array. My problem is that it seems to work fine on CodeWars website, but when I run it in Chrome console it's giving me the .filter is not a function error. I suspect its a syntax error in the arrow functions, but I can't for the life of me work it out!

```
function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(numbers) {
  const filter = numbers.filter(x => x > -1).sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return filter[0] + filter[1];
}

sumTwoSmallestNumbers(544, 32654, 34297, 9237, 343, 98); // 441
```

Comment: You haven't passed an array.

Comment: `sumTwoSmallestNumbers([544, 32654,......])`

Comment: simple debugging `function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(numbers) { console.log(numbers); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an array like so:

```js
function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(numbers) {
  const filter = numbers.filter(x => x > -1).sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return filter[0] + filter[1];
}

console.log(sumTwoSmallestNumbers([544, 32654, 34297, 9237, 343, 98])); // 441
```

Comment: christ, that's embarrassing! I was so focused on the functions that I completely missed that...

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass an array like,

```js
function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(numbers) {
  const filter = numbers.filter(x => x > -1)
  filter.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return filter[0] + filter[1];
}

console.log(sumTwoSmallestNumbers([544, 32654, 34297, 9237, 343, 98])); // 441
```

**Or** in ES6 you can use `spread` operator like,

```js
    function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(...numbers) {
      const filter = numbers.filter(x => x > -1)
      filter.sort((a, b) => a - b);
      return filter[0] + filter[1];
    }

    console.log(sumTwoSmallestNumbers(544, 32654, 34297, 9237, 343, 98)); // 441
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a method implemented on array. You have to pass the parameter (`numbers`) in the form of an array:

```js
function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(numbers) {
  const filter = numbers.filter(x => x > -1).sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return filter[0] + filter[1];
}

console.log(sumTwoSmallestNumbers([544, 32654, 34297, 9237, 343, 98]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to represent an indefinite number of arguments as an array.

```js
function sumTwoSmallestNumbers(...numbers) {
  const filter = numbers.filter(x => x > -1).sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return filter[0] + filter[1];
}

console.log(sumTwoSmallestNumbers(544, 32654, 34297, 9237, 343, 98));
```

Comment: This does work too but my mistake was not putting square brackets around my array!

Comment: @daggett - Alright. However, in future you can try this value out too as it will not require brackets :)